# Understanding of usage of Java2Wsdl for axis2/c

Tags: web-services, maven-2, installation, apache-axis, axis2c

I have a problem with the installation of Java2Wsdl tool.

I have succesfully created and compiled(generated the .class file from the .java file) a simple Java class inside a directory /home/user/examples/com/mycompany/app.
In there I compile my SimpleClass and so, I have two files: SimpleClass.java & a SimpleClass.class .

Next, I have axis2/c installed on my ubuntu system

`$ echo $AXIS2C_HOME` 
 
`/usr/local/axis2c`

I also have axis2/java installed

`echo $AXIS2_HOME` 
`/opt/axis2-1.6.2`

I also downloaded, extracted and installed from [this](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis2/axis2-java2wsdl-maven-plugin) link the java2wsdl plugin.

This is how the bin directory looks like.
`username@usernamePC:/opt/axis2-1.6.2/bin$ ls` 
`axis2.bat        axis2server.sh  java2wsdl.bat  setenv.sh      wsdl2java.sh
 axis2server.bat  axis2.sh        java2wsdl.sh   wsdl2java.bat`

Now, I want to convert my initial project from java to wsdl with java2wsdl but I cannot understand the right place of directory I should put that into, if I have the classpath(?) right and what would be the correct command for the conversion to happen.

I am trying something like that: 
 `Java2WSDL.sh -cn com.mycompany.app.SimpleClass`
In here I put `.` instead of `/` and I am typing that in top directory, meaning com directory.

Can you help me out with this?
I am sorry for the long question but I needed to set all things right.

my-app was build with a simple maven project (maven 2.2.1) through [this](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/) guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should start codegeneration from `build/classes` directory.
That directory must have `com` and `META-INF` subdirs.

Example of generating WSDL:

```
# compile your project using ant or mvn
ant
# go to binary dir
cd build/classes
# check SimpleClass.class is here
ls com/mycompany/app/SimpleClass.class
# generate WSDL into current directory
$AXIS2_HOME/bin/java2wsdl.sh -cn com.mycompany.app.SimpleClass
# see generated WSDL
cat SimpleClass.wsdl
```

To generate WSDL into different directory append `-o <directory>` switch to command line of `wsdl2java.sh` script.